# unit test javascript function that triggers a click on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I would like to test the below JavaScript function where I want to trigger  Click on the anchor tag(passed dynamically). Could someone provide any code reference to unit test the below function.

```
var clickTag = function(tagtoClick, htmlEle) {       
        var anchor = htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var anchorToClick;
        for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
            if (anchor[i].textContent.trim() === tagtoClick.trim()) {
                anchorToClick = anchor[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        anchorToClick.click();        
    };
```

I want to test that a click has been triggered,

Below is my unit test

```
 describe("Testing anchor click", function () {
        var anchorToClick;
       beforeEach(function () {
            //also tried adding below callThrough
           //spyOn(actionToClick, 'click').and.callThrough();
        });

        iit("test clickAction should click on the action", function () {
            //blah blah code
            spyOn(anchorToClick, 'click');
            abc.clickTag ("Delete",actionBar);

            expect(anchorToClick.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });       
    });
```

Comment: not able to find suitable examples using Jasmine spies. could you please elaborate more or provide any example

Comment: `spyOn(anchorToClick, 'click');` then `expect(anchorToClick.click).toHaveBeenCalled();` Thouth, you can do some refactoring to have better experience.

Comment: I tried with what you have mentioned, now i see an error "spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for click()", I have updated my post with unit test, i read that we should use Stub since the click() action is called on a variable.